# Laravel: Send slack notification after a scheduled task finished

Tags: laravel, slack

I need to schedule a few tasks on an application built using Laravel and I would like to send a slack notification after those tasks are finished with the output.

Laravel provides an "after" hook (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#task-hooks) so I can do something like this:

```
$schedule->command('mycommand')
     ->daily()
     ->after(function () {
         // How can I access the command's name and output from here?
     });
```

I've tried with `$this->output` but `$this` points to `App\Console\Kernel` and it says `Undefined property: App\Console\Kernel::$output`. I've also tried to pass a parameter to the closure, but I think I need to specify a type, but I have no idea and the documentation is not very clear.

Anyone has any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to send notification to slack on success? you want to access the command name? what do you want to do exactly? be more specific please

Comment: I want to send a notification on slack after the command finishes (no matter if it was on success or if it failed). The notification must contain the command name and the command output (The idea here is to reuse the same code for multiple scheduled tasks, since all of them are commands and each command has output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this in your command

```
$this->info('hello');
```

In your kernel, you can send the output to a temporary file and then read the file and send it

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event $command */
$command = $schedule->command('mycommand')
    ->daily()
    ->sendOutputTo('storage/app/logs.txt');

$command->after(function () use ($command) {
    \Log::debug([$command->command, $command->output]);
    \Log::debug(file_get_contents($command->output));
});
```

You will get

```
[2019-10-11 13:03:38] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => '\'/usr/bin/php7.3\' \'artisan\' command:name',
  1 => 'storage/app/logs.txt',
)  
[2019-10-11 13:03:38] local.DEBUG: hello
```

Maybe it would be the time to re-open this proposal https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/122#issuecomment-228215251

Comment: That does the job, thanks very much! However I'm having another issue now. I've wrote a notification class following docs and I'm trying to send the slack notification using the notify trait (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) but for some reason it's not being sent. I'm trying to add debug messages everywhere in the code but for some reason is not reaching or calling `toSlack($notifiable)` method.

Comment: Can you show us the code? Perhaps make a new question?

Comment: nevermind, I will accept your answer. I forgot to define a `routeNotificationForSlack` function. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Define a macro for the console scheduling event in your app service provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::macro('slackOutput', function (bool $onlyIfOutputExists = false): self {
            return $this->thenWithOutput(
                function ($output) {
                    $level = $this->exitCode === 0
                        ? 'info'
                        : 'error';

                    Log::channel('slack')
                        ->log(
                            $level,
                            $this->getEmailSubject(),
                            [
                                'output' => $output,
                            ]
                        );
                },
                $onlyIfOutputExists
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Use it like this if you want slack logs even if there's no output:

```
$schedule
    ->command('inspire')
    ->slackOutput();
```

Use it like this if you want slack logs only when there is output:

```
$schedule
    ->command('inspire')
    ->slackOutput(true);
```

I am on Laravel 9. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of output does your command generate? is it command line or is just a variable you're trying to pass to the `after()`?

Alternativly in your `handle()` method of the command you can call the desired command after all the code has been excuted, you can even pass a parameter to the command.

You can do that by using [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

```
Artisan::call('*command_name_here*');
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't get it right. Basically I want to schedule a few commands to run (like cronjobs). The idea is to run the command (like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#task-output), wait until it finishes, get the output and send a slack notification with the command name and the command output (I need the command name because I have multiple commands running on different times of the day and commands running simultaneously too).